# How do I remove string '' from python dictionary list values?

Tags: python, dictionary

The loadInventory function with a string filename as parameter reads the contents from inventory.txt

```
def loadInventory(filename):
    inventory = {}
    inventoryFile = open(filename)
    for line in inventoryFile:
        itemID,itemStock = line.split(":")
        inventory[itemID] = itemStock
        inventory = {itemID: itemStock for itemID, itemStock in inventory.items()}
        inventory[itemID] = [itemStock.replace('\n', '')]
    
    # print(f"{inventory}")
    return inventory

def main():
    print(loadInventory('Inventory.txt'))
main()
```

Inventory.txt:

```
C05:10,10,5,4
C01:0,20,10,5
C11:10,20,10,1
C03:0,0,10,0
C10:1,1,1,1
```

Output:

```
{'C05': ['10,10,5,4'], 'C01': ['0,20,10,5'], 'C11': ['10,20,10,1'], 'C03': ['0,0,10,0'], 'C10': ['1,1,1,1']}
```

Intended Output:

```
 {'C05':[10,10,5,4], 'C01':[0,20,10,5], 'C11':[10,20,10,1],
      'C03':[0,0,10,0]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
        inventory[itemID] = [itemStock.replace('\n', '')]
```

To:

```
        inventory[itemID] = [int(i) for i in itemStock.replace('\n', '').split(',')]
```

Or:

```
        inventory[itemID] = list(map(int, itemStock.replace('\n', '').split(',')]))
```